# How to enable auto postback from Paypal to my website after a successful transaction

Tags: paypal

How do I make the payment completed page (the page that shows the receipt number) to auto post back the receipt number to my website instead of having user to manually click on the link "Return to my website" ?

I prefer not to use the configuration in the Paypal setting page as ultimately this Paypal account will be used for payment collection for multiple sites, thus the "return url" required will be different.

Was hoping this can be parameterized in the form parameter in individual website instead.

Here's the code I used in the posting page btw:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="(My Email)">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="SG">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Invoice 1001">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="(Cancel Url)">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="(Success Url)">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_paynow_107x26.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Is there anything parameter that I can add to trigger the auto postback once payment is completed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it automatically returning (which still waits about 10 seconds to do so) you would need to enable Auto-Return in your PayPal account.  It should still hold the return URL you include in the separate buttons, though.

If that doesn't work out well enough for you then you could look into using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) instead, which will end up back at your site before the transaction is finalized, so you would always be able to do anything you want in that flow and wouldn't even need to worry about auto return options.